# Убираем последнию линию справа/ Убираем линию сверху

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

Столкнулась с проблемой мне нужно убрать последнию линию справа и нужно убрать линию сверху, оставить только по середине, но при попытке это сделать через first-child, last-child, nth-last-child(odd), nth-last-child(even), оно применяется ко всем моим категориям. Почему? Помогите исправить, заранее всем спасибо.
Это код:

```
<!--categories-->
        <div class="categories">
            <div class="buttonsRow rounded row">
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                    <div class="col-lg-2 myDiv" >
                        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                        <a class="c category-link btn btn-danger btn-lg loading buttonload" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i>" id="load" href="{{ route('home').'?category='.$category->url }}">{{ $category->name}}</a>
                    </div>
                @endforeach

            </div>
        </div>
        <!--//categories-->
```

```
.categories {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    //font-family: $primary-font;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 20px 0;

    @media (max-width:1270px){
        column-count: 2;
    }
}

.row.buttonsRow {
    margin-left: -4px;
    margin-right: -4px;

    > * {
        padding: 3px 5px;
        border-top: 1px groove;

    }


}



.c {
    //width: 19.9%;
    outline: none;
    padding: 16px 15px;
    //border-left: 1px solid $black-color;
    border-right: 1px solid $black-color;
    //border-radius: 9px;
    height: 56px;
    margin:  1px 2px 3px 4px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $black-color !important;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: $black-color;
    //transition: all ease 0.5s;

    @media (max-width:2800px) {
        max-height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}

.c :nth-last-child(even) {
    border-left: none;
}
.c:nth-last-child(2) {
    border-left: none;
}

.c {
    &:hover {
        background: #E2E1E1;
        color: $black-color !important;
    }

}



.active{
    background: #e6007e;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    font-weight:bold;
}
/* --//categories--*/
```

Comment: попробуй `.myDiv:last-child .c {border-left: none;}`

Comment: приложите картинку, как вы хотите, чтобы было, а то непонятно

Comment: всем спасибо, уже разобралась